# failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using this `Dockerfile` for my Django + React(Vite) application. Its giving the same error every time when I am running it with `docker-compose build`

GitHub: [click here](https://github.com/sayakongit/sangnet)

**Dockerfile (Django)**

```
FROM  python:3.10-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV EMAIL_HOST_USER=email
ENV EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=password

WORKDIR /backend

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev build-essential

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . . 

EXPOSE 8000
```

**Dockerfile (React)**

```
FROM node:20.6-buster-slim

WORKDIR /frontend

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 5173

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend        
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/frontend
```

I would appreciate if anyone can help me with solving the issue and make the build successful with dockerizing the whole application.

Comment: The command `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` should come after `COPY . .`, assuming your `requirements.txt` file is in the docker build context (directory where you are invoking the `docker` command)

Comment: What is the actual error?  "Exit code 1" just means "it didn't work", but there is usually an extended error before this.  Is the React application related to the problem?  Can you [edit] the question to clarify the actual problem, and the minimum necessary code to reproduce it?